# RabbitMQ/Spring AQMP x-queue-type ignored for quorum queue definition

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

With a Spring AQMP Java client, I am trying to publish to an existing RabbitMQ quorum queue.

As shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642540), my code defines the target queue using the `x-queue-type` argument of 'quorum':

```
@Bean
Queue queue(@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.queue.name}") String queueName) {
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, Map.of("x-queue-type", "quorum"));
    queue.setShouldDeclare(true);
    return queue;
}
```

This works fine if the queue doesn't already exist and the RabbitMQ admin console shows the new queue is created with the type 'quorum'. But if I restart my application and the queue *already* exists, the publish attempt fails with the message:

`Failed to declare queue: Queue [name=myqueuename, durable=true, autoDelete=false, exclusive=false, arguments={}, actualName=myqueuename], continuing... com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'myqueuename' in vhost 'myvhost': received none but current is the value 'quorum' of type 'longstr'`

This message occurs when the definition of the remote queue doesn't match the local queue definition. But why is it happening here? I have declared the queue with `x-queue-type` set to "quorum", and that matches the remote queue definition. You can see the first line of the log message shows `exclusive=false, *arguments={}*` which implies the map of arguments passed to the queue constructor are being ignored.

How should I define this queue so that it not only creates a quorum queue, but can also publish to it?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce it. This is a simple Spring Boot application according to your description:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So77224292Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So77224292Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("myQueue", true, false, false, Map.of("x-queue-type", "quorum"));
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return args -> rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myQueue",  new Random().nextDouble());
    }


    @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
    public void consume(String payload) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + payload);
    }

}
```

When no queue on the broker, it is created. The data published and consumed.
After restart, with the queue in place, everything still works as expected: random data published and consumed.

Perhaps you have something else you need to share with us, so we can reproduce it on our side and figure out what and where is wrong.

Comment: Are you running against a local or remote RabbitMQ broker?

Comment: Local. But if that remote then you need some specific permissions to be able to create those queues. Or just have them in advance and don't declare them in your Spring application. Or just `setShouldDeclare(false)`.

Comment: The queues are being created or reused on the remote broker without any problem, and they are marked as quorum queues. It's when I attempt to publish to the queue that I receive this error message.

Comment: As you see in sample I also do `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()` and that's exactly the moment when `RabbitAdmin` registers RabbitMQ entities - when connection is established. But anyway: it always worked well. Please, double check your solution against local broker. Then you might need to consult with that remote one to see what is the difference.

Comment: This issue doesn't happen with a local broker, only with remote brokers. The queue is created the same way regardless of whether it's local or remote. The only difference I see between them is that the local broker account is an admin and the remote broker account is not. But - why would a non-admin be able to create a quorum queue and have permissions to use it, but receive this error saying the queue definition in code is not a quorum queue?

Comment: You might have some other `Queue` definition which accidentally uses same name

Comment: Only one queue is used by the application, and the application is the only producer and only consumer of the queue.

Comment: Yeah... It would be great to have something from you where we can reproduce it and play with.